# c++ pthreads - crash while trying to lock mutex for reading

Tags: c++, crash, gdb, pthreads, mutex

Class `LocalT` have member of other class that realized `read-write-mutex`. Mutex initialized at constructor and use `pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&aMutex);` for reading lock. So, seems, its all ok with mutex class. But program crashed when some `LocalT` object lock his mutex member for reading.

`CSerialize.cpp:2054` line is `MUTEX.lock_reading();`

```
Thread 6 (Thread 0x80d4e00 (runnable)):
#0  0x4864f11d in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#1  0x4864b558 in pthread_rwlock_init () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#2  0x4864b659 in pthread_rwlock_rdlock () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#3  0x0807ae14 in LocalT::serialize (this=0x80d4e00, outbin=@0x7574736b)
    at CSerialize.cpp:2054
```

Other two running threads:

1) at socket `accept();`

2) next runnable thread at `popen()` call, seems its execute or `read` from pipe. But does not know what is `__error()` ?????

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x8614800 (LWP 100343)):
#0  0x4865b8f9 in __error () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#1  0x4865a15a in pthread_testcancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#2  0x486425bf in read () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#3  0x08056340 in UT::execute_popen (command=@0x4865e6bc,
    ptr_output=0xbf2f7d30) at Utils.cpp:75
```

3) all other thread sleeping.

I have no ideas why its crashed? Maybe somebody can assume something or suggest?

**==EDIT==**

and here is one system(?) thread ( i does not create it, but program always have +1 thread). It always:

```
Thread 8 (Thread 0x80d4a00 (LWP 100051)):
#0  0x4865a79b in pthread_testcancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#1  0x48652412 in pthread_mutexattr_init () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#2  0x489fd450 in ?? ()
```

**==EDIT2 - bt as requested==**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x4865a7db in pthread_testcancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#1  0x48652412 in pthread_mutexattr_init () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
#2  0x489fd450 in ?? ()
```

strangely... why `?? ()` ?

**==EDIT3 - when loading core==**

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[skiped]
#0  0x4865a7db in pthread_testcancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
[New Thread 0x8614800 (LWP 100343)]
[New Thread 0x8614600 (sleeping)]
[New Thread 0x8614400 (sleeping)]
[New Thread 0x8614200 (sleeping)]
[New Thread 0x8614000 (sleeping)]
[New Thread 0x80d4e00 (runnable)]
[New Thread 0x80d4c00 (sleeping)]
[New Thread 0x80d4a00 (LWP 100051)]
[New Thread 0x80d4000 (runnable)]
[New LWP 100802]

(gdb) info thread
* 10 LWP 100802  0x4865a7db in pthread_testcancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  9 Thread 0x80d4000 (runnable)  0x486d7bd3 in accept () from /lib/libc.so.6 -- MAIN() THREAD
  8 Thread 0x80d4a00 (LWP 100051)  0x4865a79b in pthread_testcancel ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 ( UNIDENTIFIED THREAD system()? ) 
  7 Thread 0x80d4c00 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 (SIGNAL PROCESSOR THREAD)
  6 Thread 0x80d4e00 (runnable)  0x4864f11d in pthread_mutex_lock ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 (MAINTENANCE THREAD)
  5 Thread 0x8614000 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 (other mutex cond_wait - worker 1)
  4 Thread 0x8614200 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 (other mutex cond_wait - worker 2 )
  3 Thread 0x8614400 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 (other mutex cond_wait - worker 3 )
  2 Thread 0x8614600 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 (other mutex cond_wait - worker 4)
  1 Thread 0x8614800 (LWP 100343)  0x4865b8f9 in __error ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 ( popen() thread see below)
```

I created: 1 maintenance thread (serializing), 1 `popen()` thread, 4 workers, 1 main, 1 signal thread = 8 threads....

Answer (score 1):

the thread that you are referring to as system thread is actually your program's `main thread`.

Secondly with information shared by you so far, it looks like you are acquiring the mutex but never releasing it. that leads to an unstable state (some parameters having wrong values) which leads to a crash. I am sure you will also be observing an intermittent hang.

could you share the `backtrace`  when it crashes ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. 1) no, main thread at `accept()` state. maybe its signal thread at `sigwait()` state 2) I will try to search the code where I use this mutex, but... seems no, I always attentive with that... 3) added + some additional information.

Comment: pls do `info threads` that will show you all the threads there are

Comment: if What i mentioned above regarding not relinquishing the lock is true you will see bunch of threads waiting on that mutex

Comment: done. "sleeping threads" are workers. they are must be at `cond_wait` states. waiting for signal from main thread.

Comment: seems like you have a bigger problem here . Seems like bunch of threads are trying to do `pthread_mutexattr_init ()` on the same mutex ? shouldn't only the main thread do that ? move this call to your `main()` function