# multithread - additional thread created by the system?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, pthreads

I am attaching with `gdb` to the running process (my multithread server). Then I request `info thread` and see that there is always +1 (or 2? ) additional thread(s), that I does not create at my code.
I created only:

- 4 workers (must be at `cond_wait()` )
- 1 signal thread ( always at `sigwait()` )
- 1 maintenance thread (executing each N seconds, then `cond_wait()` state)
- 1 thread that use `popen()` (executing each N seconds, then `cond_wait()` state)
- 1 `main()` thread (at `accept()` )

**So, = 8 thread created by me. But why reported 9 or 10 ???**

System is FreeBSD 6.4

Also, always have problem with this additional thread, it crash my program and it always at `pthread_testcancel ()` state!
[c++ pthreads - crash while trying to lock mutex for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042458/c-pthreads-crash-while-trying-to-lock-mutex-for-reading)

Seems, marked by `*` thread number 10 is currently executed thread? and its the same as 8 thread??? or I have 2 additional thread? Is it normal? thanks.. and sorry for my bad english.

```
(gdb) info thread
* 10 LWP 100108  0x4865a79b in pthread_testcancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.2 ( WHAT IS ??? (1) )
  9 Thread 0x80d4000 (runnable)  0x486d7bd3 in accept () from /lib/libc.so.6
  8 Thread 0x80d4a00 (LWP 100090)  0x4865a79b in pthread_testcancel ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2 ( WHAT IS??? (2) )
  7 Thread 0x80d4c00 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  6 Thread 0x80d4e00 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  5 Thread 0x868b000 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  4 Thread 0x868b200 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  3 Thread 0x868b400 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  2 Thread 0x868b600 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
  1 Thread 0x868b800 (sleeping)  0x48651cb6 in pthread_mutexattr_init ()
   from /lib/libpthread.so.2
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libs? If so, these libs could be creating the extra threads.

Comment: @Brady I am using 1) curl 2) ImageMagick 3) tinyxml2 4) pcrecpp ...

Comment: You should be able to switch to that thread in gdb `thread 10` and print the stack trace `bt` which should tell you what's happening there. Im pretty sure you'll see that its one of those libs you mentioned. Here's more threading help with GDB http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html

Comment: @Brady thanks, I will try to do so, does not know before about switch, but... as you can see at the linked thread, its always report `in ?? ()` about this thread... and when I attached to the `.core` and do `bt`, its also report the same as at the linked thread under `EDIT2`. strange... why `??` ? undefined place?

Comment: Make sure you compile with the '-g' flag to turn on debugging. If you have done that and still see `???` in the stack trace, that could mean the stack is corrupt.

Comment: @Brady I use `-g3` flag, maybe here is the problem with `??` ? Or why stack can become corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

The additional threads are the result of 3rd party libraries.  A quick search through curl, ImageMagick, tinyxml2, and pcre's source code shows that curl and ImageMagick have `pthread_create()` calls.

With regards to debugging in gdb:

- In `info threads`, the `*` indicating the current thread being examined.  It does not indicate the current thread running.
- On the backtrace, the `in ?? ()` can indicate that either the libraries are not built with debugging information (`-g` with gcc) or the stack is corrupted.  Generally, if the stack is corrupted, gdb will give an explicit indication.

Also, be certain to check [ImageMagick's thread of execution documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#threads).